# Unable to Connect From Dockerized Node Program to Localhost Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I am able to npm start the code from cmd and have it running with mongodb but docker build the code and docker run it generates this error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:173:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:458:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:372:17)
```

My app.js is listening in on port 8080 and i exposed port 8080 and 27017 on dockerfile. May i know what else should i be doing to resolve the error. I am a beginner on this, pardon me.

Comment: could you share your docker commands too?

Comment: docker build -t ryan/edocker .
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d ryan/edocker

Answer (score 0):

you only expose `8080` and that's why it couldn't connect to `27017`!
instead of `-p 8080:8080` use `-P` to expose 27017 too!
so you're build command would be this:

```
docker run -P -d ryan/edocker
```

Comment: is your mongo on a docker too?

Comment: Nope. Only my Node

Comment: so your mongo ip address is not `127.0.0.1`! it should be your host ip address:)

Comment: How do i go about checking what the configuration is ?
HAHA. I assumed it would work fine cause it booted up and i were able to access the website of Node when i npm start it. It only generates error when i am building it as a image to run by docker

Comment: add this to your docker run `--net=host`  and keep mongo host address as `127.0.0.1`! let me know the result!

Comment: Same error =/. 
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --net=host ryan/edocker

Comment: I tried 
docker run -P -d --net=host ryan/edocker 
Same error too